# Yelp Fusion API

Tags: ios, swift, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

I am a beginner trying to incorporate yelp's fusions API into my app but I couldn't find any proper resources on how to use the API. I am trying to use the business Search endpoint. can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using yelp for my location based restaurant viewing application.

I use `Moya` for the network requests. I have example for you:

In your codebase define your own api key!

```
import Foundation
import Moya

private let apiKey = MyConstants.shared.apiKey

enum YelpService {
enum BusinessProvider: TargetType {
    case search(lat: Double, long: Double)
    case details(id: String)

    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses")!
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .search:
            return "/search"
        case let .details(id):
            return "/\(id)"
        }
    }

    var method: Moya.Method {
        return .get
    }

    var sampleData: Data {
        return Data()
    }

    var task: Task {
        switch self {
        case let .search(lat, long):
            return .requestParameters(parameters: ["latitude": lat, "longitude": long, "limit": 10], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
        case .details:
            return .requestPlain
        }
    }

    var headers: [String: String]? {
        return ["Authorization": "Bearer \(apiKey)"]
    }
}
}
```

Your api link should look like this : `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search`

Comment: can you tell me how I would use this to display data?

Comment: Where are you use this data to display?